# (how) can 802.15 access the internet?

Tags: https, 802.15

Can I interface with my server's RESTful HTTPS API directly over 802.15?

Or do I need a gateway?

Any good overview/tutorial for 802.15 (not too in depth, just ot get an overview)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bridge/gateway.

From what little I remember from looking at LPWAN Zigbee networks a LONG time ago and assuming I've not got the wrong end of the stick...

Something that will change the physical layer of the network (Zigbee to probably ethernet/wifi) and possibly do [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (link-local IPv6 to either global unique IPv6 or IPv4)

I also used to run Bluetooth (classic) PAN that used my phone (Sony T68i iirc) as the gateway to provide internet to my PDA (in the golden years before smart phones). Bluetooth PANs would support up 8 devices and handed out private IPv4 addresses and NATed to the rest of the world.